# R Clusplot: How to represent clusters as numbers rather than shapes

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I want to plot my k means cluster on a 2d plot using clusplot(). However, the points are represented as different shapes on my plot (triangle, square, circle, etc) and it's not easy to see what each shape represents. Is there a way to either generate a legend or change the plot such that it's plotting the cluster assignment rather than a shape?

```
clusplot(data, myclus$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0)
```

Comment: Can't you adapt example from `?clusplot` for your own use?

Answer (score 2):

get help from `?clusplot.default()`, you can get more information,
you just need add a synatx in your command like this :

```
clusplot(data, myclus$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=2, lines=0, plotchar=FALSE),
```

the points will be  represented as same shapes on your plot !